# How long are Office add-in manifests cached?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

In the article below they describe how a user can delete the contents of their "Office cache" so to force re-download of an Office add-in manifest.

Is this "Office cache" periodically invalidated or purged on any kind of reliable schedule? In other words, how long are manifests persisted in the cache assuming no one has manually deleted them?

The path to the "Office cache":

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest#clear-the-office-cache

I haven't found any documentation from Microsoft online about the duration of the cache.

Comment: Cache is never cleared. Manifest has a source location tag that holds our Add-in. It is always best practice to add the hashing technique for Add-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache is never cleared automatically.